# QTiles replacement for QGIS3

Tags: qgis-3, mbtiles

[QTiles](https://github.com/nextgis/QTiles) for QGIS v2 generated what I think are called slippy tiles. Apparently follow ons ran into [complications](https://github.com/nextgis/QTiles/issues/94). [Tiles XYZ](https://github.com/lutraconsulting/qgis-xyz-tiles) was "a stop-gap for QGIS 3.4 LTR users." and they said "for QGIS 3.8 and above, you do not need this plugin. The functionality is available from core processing toolbox."

Where is that funtionality?

I've searched the manual released Mar 06, 2020 and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

I found it Menu: Processing > Processing Toolbox (Toolbox) > Raster tools > Generate XYZ Tiles.